# Summation of prolog predicates not working

Tags: prolog

Like the title states, I am trying to return the sum of the returned values from sub predicates but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
addlistnum([],[],X).
addlistnum(digits(Y,[A|T]),digits(F,[B|T]),X) :-
   X is Y + F.

digits(Num, List) :-
   digits(0, List, Num).

digits(Num, [], Num).
digits(N, [A|As], Num) :-
   N1 is N * 10 + A,
   digits(N1, As, Num).
```

The sub predicate works fine. It converts list to an integer. Now I want to sum the converted values.
Example:

```
?- digits(X,[3,3,3]).
X = 333.                % works as expected
```

Building on that, `addlistnum([3,3,3,3],[2,2,2],X)` is supposed to produce `X = 3555` (as `3555 is 3333 + 222`), but I get `false` instead.

I also tried:

```
addlistnum([],[],X).
addlistnum([A|T],[B|T],X) :-
   X is Y + F,
   digits(Y,[A|T]), 
   digits(F,[B|T]).
```

It simply returns `false`, which gives no information about is wrong.

Comment: There's fundamental misunderstandings here. Your predicate clause head: `addlistnum(digits(Y,[A|T]),digits(F,[B|T]),X)` seems to imply you think of `digits` as a function that returns a value, but it doesn't work that way. When you call, `addlistnum([3,3,3,3], [2,2,2], X)`, Prolog attempts to match the term `[3,3,3,3]` to the term, `[]` or to `digits(Y, [A|T])` and it fails because they clearly don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is at these rules:

```
addlistnum([],[],X).
addlistnum(digits(Y,[A|T]),digits(F,[B|T]),X) :-
   X is Y + F.
```

Second one is, "addition of two list is the addition of the integer conversion of these list":

```
addlistnum(A,B,X) :-
   digits(NA,A),
   digits(NB,B),
   X is NA + NB.
```

first one is not necessary,  "digits" for an empty list is zero, thus, this rule also covers "addition of two empty list is zero"